# Strapi not uploading pictures to Cloudinary

Tags: strapi, cloudinary

**UPDATE: I installed Strapi version 3.6.3 and it works well**

Strapi - Clouinary connection do not work for me. So I'm uploading pictures to Stapi, but they don't appear in Clouinary.

In config folder I created file **plugins.js** with following content:

```
module.exports = ({
  env
}) => ({
  // ...
  upload: {
     provider: 'cloudinary',
     providerOptions: {
        cloud_name: env('CLOUDINARY_NAME'),
        api_key: env('CLOUDINARY_KEY'),
        api_secret: env('CLOUDINARY_SECRET'),
     },
  },
  // ...
});
```

I have installed `npm i strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary`

then changed file .env to

````
PORT=1337
CLOUDINARY_NAME="***"
CLOUDINARY_KEY="***"
CLOUDINARY_SECRET="***"```

Actually automatically following code added automatically:
```JWT_SECRET=*********
API_TOKEN_SALT=*********
JWT_SECRET=*********
````

What could be a problem?
should CLOUDINARY_SECRET be in "quotes"? or in 'quotes' or without quotes?

Terminal output after adding image is following:

```
http://localhost:1337

[2021-12-07 02:10:14.702] http: POST /upload (261 ms) 200
[2021-12-07 02:10:14.744] http: GET /upload/files?sort=updatedAt:DESC&page=1&pageSize=10 (24 ms) 200
[2021-12-07 02:10:14.758] http: GET /uploads/thumbnail_Screenshot_2021_11_26_130226_11a95e81ea.png?width=1504&height=1258 (4 ms) 200
```

All permissions seems to be set...

Also created extentions/upload/config/setting.json with the following content:

````
    "provider": "cloudinary",
    "providerOptions": {     "cloud_name":"devert0mt",
      "api_key": "***",               
      "api_secret":"***"
    }
  }{
    "provider": "cloudinary",
    "providerOptions": {     "cloud_name":"devert0mt",
      "api_key": "***",               
      "api_secret":"***"
    }
  }```
````

Comment: You shouldn't post your Cloudinary API Secret publicly. I recommend changing your current access keys ASAP. This can be done on the security tab on your Cloudinary dashboard.

Comment: I believe the keys should be without quotes. And I second what @RoeeBen-Ari said previously: never post your secret keys publicly. There's a reason they're called secret keys... Obtain new keys from Cloudinary and remove the ones you posted ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the **latest version of Strapi, v.4 and above**, you need to change strapi provider package to this one:

`npm install @strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary --save`

Then, you need to update your `plugins.js` file in `config/plugins.js` to the following ( Be aware that it has a slightly different structure than the previous package - everything is placed in **config** object, instead of **upload** like it was on a previous version):

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  // ...
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: 'cloudinary',
      providerOptions: {
        cloud_name: env('CLOUDINARY_NAME'),
        api_key: env('CLOUDINARY_KEY'),
        api_secret: env('CLOUDINARY_SECRET'),
      },
      actionOptions: {
        upload: {},
        delete: {},
      },
    },
  },
  // ...
});
```

Also, if you are having issues with properly rendering your images on your Strapi dashboard you can update `middlewares.js` in `config/middlewares.js`:

Instead of `'strapi::security'` in `module.exports`, paste this:

```js
// ...
  {
    name: 'strapi::security',
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          'connect-src': ["'self'", 'https:'],
          'img-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'blob:', 'res.cloudinary.com'],
          'media-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'blob:', 'res.cloudinary.com'],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
// ...
```

Comment: I have the same problem... But my config is up to date with the latest packages... Still doesnt work tho... Does it have something to do with working locally or in production?

Comment: Never mind, i had "plugin.js" instead of "plugins.js" as a foldername! Its works now.. stupid mistake... ‍♂️

Comment: wow @mikeyfe6 you're a lifesaveer, I have been trying to figure out why the images only uploaded to local. changing the file name to plugins.js worked!

Comment: You're welcome(, i think....)  @GameBoy

Answer (score 2):

If you do all the configuration in latest version but it won't work, maybe this is the solution. I check the name of file is `config/plugins.js` not `config/plugin.js`. This file must have `s`. LOL

Comment: Another one saved by a single 's'! Thanks!