# Strapi 4.11.5 not working with cloudinary

Tags: strapi, cloudinary, media-library

I followed this [article](https://strapi.io/blog/add-cloudinary-support-to-your-strapi-application)  to set up cloudinary with my strapi application, but it didn't work. Found an similar question in Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253875/strapi-not-uploading-pictures-to-cloudinary#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20use%20the%20latest%20version,package%20to%20this%20one%3A%20npm%20install%20%40strapi%2Fprovider-upload-cloudinary%20--save). Then I found out there was an issue with cloudinary [here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/11798). Read and verified carefully, made several changes... But no matter what I did it always upload media to the public/uploads folder instead of cloudinary.

So I also open a bug in strapi [here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/17330). But there is no response or answer from anyone. So, I ask a question here in a hope that someone can help me out.

Below is the information to reproduce the issue:

System infomration:

- Node.js version: 18.16.1
- NPM version: 8.3.1
- JavaScript

### package.json

```
"devDependencies": {},
    "dependencies": {
        "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.11.5",
        "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.11.5",
        "@strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary": "4.11.5",
        "@strapi/strapi": "4.11.5",
        "pg": "8.8.0"
    },
```

### ./config/plugins.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    upload: {
        config: {
            provider: "cloudinary",
            providerOptions: {
                cloud_name: env("CLOUDINARY_NAME"),
                api_key: env("CLOUDINARY_KEY"),
                api_secret: env("CLOUDINARY_SECRET"),
            },
            actionOptions: {
                upload: {},
                uploadStream: {},
                delete: {},
            },
        },
    },
});
```

### ./config/middlewares.js

```
module.exports = [
    "strapi::errors",
    {
        name: "strapi::security",
        config: {
            contentSecurityPolicy: {
                useDefaults: true,
                directives: {
                    "connect-src": ["'self'", "https:"],
                    "img-src": ["'self'", "data:", "blob:", "res.cloudinary.com"],
                    "media-src": ["'self'", "data:", "blob:", "res.cloudinary.com"],
                    upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
                },
            },
        },
    },
  // ...
];
```

Configured roles and permissions in strapi dashboard properly and verified with Postman.

Everything seems work fine, no error, but images are always saved in the public/uploads folder instead of cloudinary. Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: It may be needed to check on the version of [Strapi you used as indicated here](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4411758853778/comments/4411801361810). Additionally, here are other references that could help to provide some guidance on the config for Cloudinary in Strapi environment - see this [documentation](https://cptcrunchy.medium.com/configuring-cloudinary-with-strapi-3-1-4-6dbddc721617) and [this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71351433/uploading-asset-to-strapi-with-cloudinary-gives-error-enotempty-directory-not).

Comment: I created a fresh new strapi app with the exact same configuration for cloudinary upload plugin. Everything works as expected. I still don't know what caused the issue and will update here if I can find out the root cause. Also, I closed the bug reported earlier. Thank you.